# ClLocationManager delegate is not being called right away?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to get my current location using cllocationmanager.

**Problem:**

The delegate method

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

always runs after the viewdidappear. I startupdatingLocation in the viewDidLoad. And call a method SetMapView at the end of the viewdidLoad .

```
-(void)setMapView{

MKCoordinateRegion zoomIn = plotsMapView.region;
zoomIn.span.latitudeDelta  = 0.2;
zoomIn.span.longitudeDelta  = 0.2;



zoomIn.center.latitude =  self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;//[[[m_CityMarkerArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
zoomIn.center.longitude = self.currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;//[[[m_CityMarkerArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];



NSLog(@"%f LAT",self.currentLocation.coordinate.latitude);

[plotsMapView setRegion:zoomIn animated:YES];



}
```

the LAT is returned 0.0000.

BUT if I call the same method in viewDidAppear it works fine. 
And I need it in the viewdidload because everytime I come back to view.I reloads the map to the base location if I call the method in viewDidAppear.

Please Help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your **setMapView** method inside **didUpdateToLocation** method, provided you set your location manager delegate to **self** and added **CLLocationManagerDelegate** in your .h file. Inside your didUpdateToLocation, before calling your setMapView method, assign the newLocation coordinates to your currentLocation coordinates.

Comment: Thanks !! Dunno why din I think about it:|